# How to create a byte file?

Tags: c, file, endianness

I'm making a **C/POSIX** program that manipulates matrices written in files.

I want each matrix to be written in a different file with the following format:

1. All numbers are written as **byte sequence** following the *endiannes* of the computer
2. All numbers are written in the file **row by row**

So, for example in a *little-endian* computer with 32 bit `int`, the following matrix:

```
| 100 200 |
| 300 400 |
| 500 600 |
```

Would be stored in a byte sequence we can represent like this (where each number represents the decimal value of the corresponding byte):

```
100 0 0 0 200 0 0 0 44 1 0 0 244 1 0 0 88 2 0 0
```

As I have to test my program, **how do I create such input files**?

Comment: what you have shown is not a byte sequence, but a sequence of characters representing the decimal representation of the numerical value of these bytes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I edited the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution to the problem: I created a program (`matrix_creator`) that receives as arguments the `path` of the output file (`argv[1]`) and all numbers it needs to write in the output file (`argv[2]`, `argv[3]`,...).

I excluded all error controls to make the code easier to read:

```
int fd = open(path, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644); // Create output file
for(int i = 2; i < argc; i++) { // Starts from argv[2]
    int t = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 0); // Parse each input number
    write(fd, &t, sizeof(t)); // Write the number in the given format
}
close(fd);
```

In such a way I can **create different files using the same program for several tests**.

To check what's inside the file I installed `ghex`.

Comment: I will accept my own answer as it's the solution I finally used to solve my problem, but I upvoted both answers I received as I found both of them very useful.

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   FILE *fp;
   fopen_s(&fp, "testfile.dat", "wb");
   int i[] = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600 };
   fwrite(i, sizeof(i), 1, fp);
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Gives me a file that looks like this in Visual Studio's binary editor:

```
64 00 00 00 C8 00 00 00 2C 01 00 00 90 01 00 00
F4 01 00 00 58 02 00 00
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply write out the data

```
 int x = testvalue;
 fwrite(&x, 1, sizeof(int), fp);
```

However the Posix specification is awful. If the width of an int or the endianness of the computer changes, the file breaks. That seems to be the required behaviour.

Check out my github project on binary file portability

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/ieee754

it's much better to write out binary files so that the file, not the computer, specifies the format. And then read portably. (With floating point it is hard, with integers there are a few gotchas and it's not totally simple).